# Google HTML5 looping gone

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5

Previously it was possible to loop Youtube videos by double right clicking on the video frame and checking loop. Now when I double right click, this is gone. In the screenshot below you can see what I mean. On the left is what the menu used to look like, on the right you have the current UI. Why is it gone? And how can I restore the previous functionality without installing chrome extensions?

[image]

Also I did edit out a plugin, but that is not really relevant, disabling it still leaves the same right click menu, even after a page reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was added back into chrome:

[Quiet a while ago too](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=538694), so just update chrome and this issue will be gone.